# Can original text be edited in translate interface or elsewhere?

Tags: i18n-l10n

When translating strings in the translate interface, I would also like to be able to edit the "original text" (for the default language), and not only fill in the translation strings for other languages.

Indeed, it's no secret you regularly have to modify or improve the text of a website pages. If the website is multilingual, each time you make such a change, you have to do all this foe each piece of text :

1. recreate the translation set by reloading the involved page/template
   in the desired language
2. find and delete the initial translation set in the translate
   interface
3. refill the new translation set with the same translation as the
   original one in the translate interface

It would bee so much easier to be able to edit the original source text of the initial translation set...

Maybe I'm missing this feature somewhere... can anyone help me on this ?
Thanks you so much for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module to change the original strings.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.
>
> Features
>
> - Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
> - Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need a few easy text changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I heard about this module but I read that it could also cause performance issues, si I didn't dare to try it. I'll give it shot though and see what happens.

Comment: I just tried but it's not what I'm looking for : I'm not trying to override my source strings but to edit them. Is there anything closer to what I'm looking for ?